# Messenger in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, error-handling, messenger

After i restart laptop, visual studio don't turn off, then i open it again, It shows many lines on tabs.
"Feature 'Asset synchronization' is currently unavailable due to an internal error. Show Stack Trace"

Comment: What does this have to do with messenger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do these things:**

- Press Alt + Ctrl + Del
- Select Task Manager.
- Click on "More details" on the left side below of the Task Manager.
- Then, click the Start button.
- Find Visual Studio in this list, then click on it.
- Click "Disable" after right-clicking on Visual Studio.

Then close the window, and your problem will be solved.